# Insert data into database [Delphi]

Tags: sql, database, delphi, ado

I'm trying using a TAdoTable component,

- On form Create I call .Append() and in a button i call .Post()

but it loads the entire table! I don't need it to load anything, just need to insert a row into this table.

I was wondering if there is "good way" of inserting data into database with Ado, i already tried using the a "manual" approach with TAdoCommand but it doesn't seems right to me

- I generate the INSERT query using Format() and all string fields are escaped with QuotedStr()

Thanks in advance!

Arthur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a TADODataset (or TADOQuery).

The way I do it sometimes is with by setting the CommandText to return 0 records from the table, i.e. `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM [table]`, then use `.Append` and `.Post`

But personally, I prefer writing the SQL, such as with a TADOCommand

Comment: This is what i was looking for. It's not pretty to "manually" mount an insert with 13 fields.

Comment: instead of "select top 0" you can also use a where clause like "select * from Table where PrimaryKeyField = 0". Just make sure to use a value that will never exist in the table

Answer (score 6):

Use the TADOQuery object if you don't need to display the table's data.

Basically:

- Use TADOQuery.SQL.Text to set the SQL command
- Use TADOQuery.ExecSQL method to fire the SQL command

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the TADOCommand component, and have it execute the specific SQL command.  If you find yourself performing the same command over and over again (like inserts into a table) then consider using parameters rather than directly changing the SQL for every call.  Parameters are easy to use, just place a :PARAMNAME in your sql, then use the parameters object on the ado component your using to set the value.  For example:

Assuming the CommandText of the TAdoCommand component contains "`INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1) VALUES (:FIELDVALUE1)`"

```
AdoCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('FIELDVALUE1').Value := 'TEST'
AdoCommand1.Execute;
```

When the above sql is executed, then the string "TEST" would be written to FIELD1.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  CountVar: Integer;

begin

  TADOConnection1.Execute(ASQLInsertStatement, CountVar, [adExecuteNoRecords]);

end;
```